# Double Form Submission JSP Servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets

i am new to JSP and Servlet. I having a form in JSP example (register.jsp) that help me to send data to Servlet in order to insert values to database. However, after I've inserted successfully, and if i hit on the same URL as (register.jsp) , it resubmit the same data that I've entered previous to my database again. how do i prevent this case? Below are my Code

JSP

```
  <form action="ServletComment" method="post" class="form-inline" role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Your comments" name="userComment" />
             <input type="hidden" name="Action" value="updateComment" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-default"> Add</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Servlet

```
String checkComment = null;
    checkComment = request.getParameter("Action");

    if(checkComment.equals("updateComment"))
    {
        // my coding
    }

request.getRequestDispatcher("/register.jsp").forward(request,response);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may probably receiving request in your `servlet` in a common method. You should `override` different method for different `HTTP` request. Like:

```
    //here only http get request will go in this method
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            //do whatever you want
        }


    //here only http post request will go in this method    
        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            String checkComment = null;
            checkComment = request.getParameter("Action");

            if(checkComment.equals("updateComment"))
             {
                // my coding
             }

            request.getRequestDispatcher("/register.jsp").forward(request,response);
        }
```